# ClearCanvas PixelData

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

I want to change a dicom file's pixeldata.

Directly, that is change it in the image.

But I can't find methods in CC(ClearCanvas) program what I can use!

Also, I do not understand the property of "Rows" and "Colunms".

Answer (score 0):

I have modified pixel data this but not using ClearCanvas. ClearCanvas is an image viewer so I am not sure if this is capable of doing what you are trying to do. Libraries that will do this include DCM4CHE, ImageJ, Pixelmed.

The DICOM standard explains what each tag means. You can find the standard on Wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM

It will tell you what exactly the tags `Rows` and `Columns` mean.